# How to see the error of open()

Tags: c, debugging, error-handling, named-pipes, errno

I am working with pipes and one pipe won't open, even though `mkfifo()` was successful.

I have this:

```
/* create the FIFO (named pipe) */
int ret_mk = mkfifo(out_myfifo, 0666);
if(ret_mk < 0) {
  perror(out_myfifo);
  unlink(out_myfifo);
  return -1;
}

printf("ret_mk = %d\n", ret_mk);
/* write to the FIFO */
out_fd = open(out_myfifo, O_WRONLY);
printf("out_fd = %d\n", out_fd);
```

but nothing gets printed after `open()`, even a print of random text won't show up.

From [here](http://gd.tuwien.ac.at/languages/c/programming-bbrown/c_075.htm) we have:

> The `open()` function returns an integer value, which is used to refer to the file. If unsuccessful, it returns -1, and sets the global variable `errno` to indicate the error type.

What can I do to see why it won't open?

Comment: Your code does not show how you know that `mkfifo()` was successful.  You'd have to capture or test the value returned by `mkfifo()` and demonstrate that it was 0 to know that `mkfifo()` was successful. And, as you now know, if you don't see the file descriptor number printed, it is because the `open()` has not completed, because no process has the FIFO open for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [fifo(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html). For FIFOs, an `open` call may block. To make [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) non-blocking, use `O_NONBLOCK` in the flag argument:

```
out_fd = open(out_myfifo, O_WRONLY|O_NONBLOCK);
if (out_fd<0) perror(out_myfifo);
printf("%d\n", out_fd);
```

But *usually* you want a blocking `open` for write on a FIFO, because some other process should `open` the *same* FIFO for reading (and you want your writing process to wait that to happen).

Notice that there is no way to [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) the event that someone else has opened the other end of your FIFO (because `poll` wants an opened file descriptor). See also [inotify(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html); you could also want to use [unix(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) sockets.

BTW, you could also use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) for debugging purposes.

See also [intro(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/intro.2.html) and [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/).

Comment: Ok I see what you mean by blocking. Do you know why my question was voted down?

Comment: I guess because of RTFM. I did not downvote your question, but a question whose answer is immediately available in man pages is not "showing research effort"

Comment: The reference I had didn't cover that up. Anyway, so that means that the question is not helpful for the site, but I can't delete it because of your answers, what I should do now? :/ By the way, do you think it's a -1 question?

Comment: But you should always (on Linux & POSIX systems) try first to RTFM. See and *use* [man(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/man.1.html) & [Linux manpages online](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/). On Debian or Ubuntu, install the `manpages` & `manpages-dev` & `manpages-posix` & `manpages-posix-dev` packages!

Comment: I'll keep that in mind Basile, thanks. Now the scarf of -1 will be forever with me! haha

Comment: BTW, in the late 1980s I learned all on Unix (SunOS3.2 at that time on Sun3) by reading man pages, from section 1 to section 8. It was harsh but very instructive! (At that time the Web did not even exist)

Comment: Well that's something for a student like me to remember!